# Making a requests.post to access a subpage with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using BeautifulSoup on Python, I'm trying to scrape a subpage of this page

`https://www.mmorpg-stat.eu/0_fiche_alliance.php?pays=5&ftr=500208.all&univers=_146`

More precisely, the subpage titled OTHER INFORMATION whose button has this code

```
onclick="fcache12('faCacher');fcache13('ffond_gris');
    document.form1_2date.statview.value='2';
    document.forms['form1_2date'].submit();return false;"
```

which calls the methods `fcache12()` and `fcache13()` and then it finds the form `form1_2date` and submits it using the value `value='2'` (values 0 and 1 are for the previous two buttons)

```
<form name="form1_2date" method="post">
```

The problem is that by clicking on the button the url doesn't change so the page cannot be reached with `requests.get()`, but `requests.post()` should be used instead.

```
import requests, urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mmorpg-stat.eu/0_fiche_alliance.php?pays=5&ftr=500208.all&univers=_146'
input = {} # what to put here?
response = requests.post(url, data = input)
```

I read that to simulate a click on the button I have to determine the form values that should be passed in, and that these are determined by all of the `<input>` tags in the form.

There are 12 `<input>`s inside `form1_2date`

```
1 <input name="keyf" id="keyf" type="hidden">
2 <input type="checkbox" name="zoomgraph_box" id="zoomgraph_box">
3 <input type="checkbox" name="zoomgraph_box" id="zoomgraph_box">
4 <input name="Submit" type="button" onclick="fcache12('faCacher');fcache13('ffond_gris');document.getElementById('menu_live_a').style.display='none';
document.form1_info3.zoomgraph.value=document.getElementsByName('zoomgraph_box')[0].checked;document.form1_info3.choixflash.value=document.getElementsByName('zoomgraph_box')[1].checked;
document.forms['form1_info3'].submit();return false;" style="font:9pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border: thin solid #666666; cursor:pointer; background:#EA6C11; color: #ffffff;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; " value="Apply">
5 <input name="Submit2" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('menu_live_a').style.display='none';" style="font:9pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border: thin solid #666666; cursor:pointer;background:#EA6C11; color: #ffffff;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; " value="Cancel">
6 <input name="date_1" type="text" class="case_ss1 hasDatepicker" id="datepickera" value="13-10-2019" size="10" maxlength="10">
7 <input name="date_2" type="text" class="case_ss1 hasDatepicker" id="datepicker" value="19-10-2019" size="10" maxlength="10">
8 <input name="plot_1" type="hidden" id="plot_1">
9 <input name="Submit" type="button" onclick="fcache12('faCacher');fcache13('ffond_gris');document.getElementById('cache_date_j_div').style.display='none';document.form1_2date.plot_1.value='6';document.form1_2date.keyf.value='';document.forms['form1_2date'].submit();return false;" style="font:9pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border: thin solid #666666; cursor:pointer; background:#EA6C11; color: #ffffff;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; " value="Apply">
10 <input name="Submit2" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('cache_date_j_div').style.display='none';" style="font:9pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;border: thin solid #666666; cursor:pointer; background:#EA6C11; color: #ffffff;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; " value="Cancel">
11 <input name="statview" type="hidden" id="statview" value="">
12 <input name="statview_bis" type="hidden" id="statview_bis" value="">
```

I read that the dictionary has to be written in the form `{'key1': value1, 'key2': value2, ...}` but I don't understand how to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web browser, open the dev tools (you can do so by pressing `F12`)

Then open the `network` tab, there you will see every request your browser make.

Now, click on the `Other information` button on the webpage.  So then, in the dev tools you'll see a few requests being made, the one that you need is this one:

[image: Dev tools screenshot]

When you select it, it opens the details of the request on the right side panel.

So to make your request work, you have to mimic this; on the screenshot is shown the `Params` tab, which is probably the most important, but there are also cookies you'll need to get (you can use `requests.Session` for the PHPSESSID)

This works :

```
import requests

response = requests.post(
        'https://www.mmorpg-stat.eu/0_fiche_alliance.php?pays=5&ftr=500208.all&univers=_146',
        data = {
            'date_1': '01-10-2019',
            'date_2': '19-10-2019',
            'statview': 2,
        }
    )

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is even possibile to just write `data = {'statview': 2}`

Comment: @soundwave That corresponds to the code you see in the `onclick` handler: `document.form1_2date.statview.value='2';` but is not sufficient to get the exact behavior you need. You also need to supply `date_`1` and `date_2` as shown in the code snippet in this answer.

Comment: maybe dates are optional and are only used to filter the results on a specific timeline ?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I tried several times, dates are not necessary since the info showed in the "Other information" page are about the last day and the timeframe cannot be changed.